# Programmatically folding in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, folding, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a (clean) way to programmatically fold/unfold methods (or a bit more lowlevel: an internval of lines) in a JDT-Editor in Eclipse.

I already read documentation about the basic concept of folding (master documents, projection documents), but the documentation didn't help me out so far.

An alternative I ran over is the so-called SWTBot, which could be used to "emulate" a click on the fold/unfold button of the editor, but I currently consider this as an ugly hack.

Has anyone ever did something similar or has a clue/example?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but looking at JavaEditor.class in JDT I saw the following code:

```
IJavaElement[] elements = ....;
    IJavaFoldingStructureProviderExtension  extension=  (IJavaFoldingStructureProviderExtension) JavaPlugin.getDefault().getFoldingStructureProviderRegistry().getCurrentFoldingProvider();
    extension.collapseElements(elements);
    extension.expandElements(elements);
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it has no visible reaction.
I tried it using the following code:
    ...
    ICompilationUnit c = ...; // This a class
    IJavaElement[] elements = c.getAllTypes()[0].getMethods();
    extension.collapseElements(elements);

While debugging I found all methods in the array, but the call didn't affect the identation.

Comment: If you think my answer was helpful, please mark it as solution.